# How to properly add a pandas timedelta to pandas datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

Hello I have the following issue when adding `pd.to_timedelta` to `pd.to_datetime` object.

So when I am using:

```
from datetime import timedelta
seconds_per_datapoint = 0.001024
staticDate

pd.to_datetime(staticDate) + timedelta(seconds=(63966 * seconds_per_datapoint))
pd.to_datetime(staticDate) + pd.to_timedelta((63966 * seconds_per_datapoint), unit='s')
```

I get the following:

```
numpy.datetime64('2021-08-09T10:03:02.000000')

Timestamp('2021-08-09 10:04:07.501184')

Timestamp('2021-08-09 10:04:07.501183999')
```

The expected result is `2021-08-09 10:04:07.501184`

I believe that this is caused by some kind of overflow.

I can not use timedelta when working with pd.Series, so what is the proper way to add a timedelta to a pd.datetime object?

Using Pandas 1.1.5

**EDIT:**

When changing the unit to 'us' and change the calculation it seems to solve it, but I dont like this method.

```
pd.to_datetime(staticDate) + pd.to_timedelta(63966 * seconds_per_datapoint * 1e6, unit='us')
```

Comment: The difference between the actual value and the expected value that you report is 1e-9 seconds. A `pandas` datetime is a 64-bit floating-point quantity, and that difference is at the edge of what a 64-bit float can represent. The quantity is not a sum of powers of 2, so it can not be accurately represented physically.

Comment: @BoarGules Hi thanks for your comment. The expected value is 1e-6 seconds (the shorter one) and it should be fine? I had roughly 1 million rows of data, and found that some rows have this issue, when calculating with timedelta.

Comment: I can't tell you *It'll be fine* because I don't know what you will be using the value for. I *can* tell you that you will find it somewhere between hard and impossible in `pandas` to get a better approximation of what you consider to be the true value.